# React state is empty even it does have a value

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, next.js

```
const CourseTags = () => {
    const [tags, setTags] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const jwt = sessionStorage.getItem("jwt")

        // GET tags
        fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST}/api/tags`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${jwt}`
            }
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                setTags(data)
                console.log(data) // <<<<<<< shows Array of tags [ {}, {}, ... ]
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }, [])


    const deleteTag = (tagId) => {

        if (confirm("Delete Tag?")) {
            console.log(tags, tagId) // <<<<<<<<< tags = [ ]
         }
    }


    return (
      <Fragment>
           <TagsList tagsList={tags} handleDeleteTag={(tagId) => deleteTag(tagId)} />
      </Fragment>
)
}
```

When invoking deleteTag function .. it shows tagsList as [ ]

// console.log(tags, tagId) shows -->
// [] '63d65592bac78b25feb8f482'

*** knowing that I am calling deleteTag(tagId) from another sub-component  ***

Comment: this is a small part of the code, show the rest

Comment: can you add the whole code, and how are you calling deleteTag inside the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've missed the dependency array ***[tagsList]*** inside my ***sub-component's*** useMemo()
once added it resolved the issue

```
const TagsList = ({tagsList, handleDeleteTag}) => {

      const columns = useMemo(() => [{}, {}, ...] , [tagsList]) // <<<< [tagsList] was missed

    .....

}
```

thanks for help,